# typescript object property has data, parent object shows same property as empty

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I'm seeing some strange behavior where an array which is the property of an object appears populated when logged to the console (and used in other places), but when the parent object is logged, it shows the property as being empty. When this parent object is returned to the calling function, the property remains empty.

Here's the Menu class:

```
import { MenuItem } from './menu-item';

export class Menu {
  category: string;
  label?: string;
  itemArray: MenuItem[] = [];
  displayArray: MenuItem[] = [];
  masterArray: MenuItem[] = [];
  singleChoice: boolean = false;
  isDisplaying: boolean = true;
  isCategory( s: string ) { return this.category = s; };
}
```

Here's the MenuItem class (it can be used in a more elaborate fashion than shown here):

```
import { Menu } from './menu';

export class MenuItem {
  label: string;
  value: string;
  children: MenuItem[] = [];
  parentMenu: Menu;
  isSelected: boolean = false;
  isCategory( s: string ) { return this.parentMenu.category = s; };
  hideFromMenu: boolean = false;
}
```

And here's some code that constructs these objects. Note that when the category is "date", and the item's properties are hard-coded, the itemArray is populated both by itself and when viewed through its parent object in the console. It's for all other categories that it fails.

```
initializeMenu(category: string, categoryName: string): Menu {
  let m = new Menu();
  m.category = category;
  m.label = this.categoryNameArray[this.categoryArray.indexOf(category)]? this.categoryNameArray[this.categoryArray.indexOf(category)]: category;
  switch( category ) {
    case "date":
      let propArray = [
                        {label:"Today",value:"today",hideFromMenu:false},
                        {label:"Day",value:"day",hideFromMenu:true},
                        {label:"This Week",value:"this week",hideFromMenu:false},
                        {label:"Next Week",value:"next week",hideFromMenu:false},
                        {label:"This Month",value:"this month",hideFromMenu:false},
                        {label:"Month",value:"month",hideFromMenu:true}
                      ];
      for(let p of propArray) {
        let i: MenuItem = new MenuItem();
        i.label = p.label;
        i.value = p.value;
        i.hideFromMenu = p.hideFromMenu;
        i.parentMenu = m;
        m.itemArray.push(i);
        // if( ! p.hideFromMenu ) m.displayArray.push(i);
      }
      m.isDisplaying = false;
      m.singleChoice = true;
      m.displayArray = this.getDisplayableDates(m.itemArray);
      m.masterArray = m.itemArray;
      return m;
      // break;
    default:
      let categoryIDs = this.makeContentSet(this.getMenuItemIDs(this.contentItems,category));
      for(let id of categoryIDs){
        let mi = new MenuItem();
        mi.parentMenu = m;
        mi.label = id;
        mi.value = id;
        m.itemArray.push(mi);
      }
      m.displayArray = m.itemArray;
      // m.displayArray = m.itemArray.filter(function(i){return ! i.hideFromMenu});
      m.isDisplaying = false;
      m.singleChoice = false;
      m.masterArray = m.itemArray;
// THIS IS WHERE IT GETS WEIRD. THE FIRST LOG SHOWS A POPULATED 
// m.displayArray, THE SECOND LOG SHOW A PARENT OBJECT WITH POPULATED   
// VALUES FOR EACH ARRAY, THE THIRD LOG SHOWS EMPTY VALUES FOR THE ARRAYS
// IN m. WEIRDER, m SHOWS POPULATED ARRAYS WHEN COLLAPSED IN THE CONSOLE, 
// BUT EMPTY ONES WHEN EXPANDED. SEE SCREENSHOT.
      console.log(m.displayArray);
      console.log(Object.values(m));
      console.log(m);
      return m;
      // break;
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot of app and console log]

Comment: Note, this is part of an Angular 2 app. I don't think that matters here, though.

Comment: I think this is actually a bug in Chrome. It's just the console that's weird. I found that my app's issue was due to something else, but that was being hidden by this bad debug info.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually a bug in Chrome. It's just the console that's weird. I found that my app's issue was due to something else, but that was being hidden by this bad debug info.

Comment: Hover over the `i` next to Menu. It's not a bug, it's a misunderstanding of what toggling that arrow does.

Comment: Thanks. I just poured through the Chrome console docs, and there is no mention of what exactly is shown when you click that arrow. There is a bit about the fact that you can get it to show it in xml, etc., but nothing about when that object is being calculated. And why would calculating it later mean that the arrays were empty? If the arrays were empty the app would be updated to those effects, and it's not.

Comment: I would suggest logging something like `JSON.stringify(m)` (if there's no circular references); that will get you the object structure as it was when the log occurred. I didn't look into why your problem was occurring, just wanted to give you the heads up that the initial log and the values in the object are out of sync.